# Pandas Skip rows on cell values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I a writing a small python script to convert the excel into cvs, but there are few rows which I  need to eliminate before my cvs:

my current code is:

```
df = pd.read_excel(input_file, sheetname, skiprows=7, usecols=("A:E"))
data = df.values
```

So for example: here I don't want rows where census-included is NO, Nopes, and Error in my datasets.

```
0.      USA       TX       87.89        Yes
1.      USA       VA       897.0        Yes 
2.      USA       VA       697.0        Yes 
3.      USA       VA       597.0        Error 
4.      USA       VA       497.0        Nopes
5.      USA       NY       297.0        No
6.      USA       FL       897.0        Yes
7.      USA       NY       297.0        No
8.      USA       FL       897.0        Yes
9.      USA       GA       897.0        Y
10.     USA       AL       897.0        YES
11.     USA       KY       897.0        YES
```

Comment: After read the excel into pandas , check isin ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is somehow a duplicate. Anyway you could just remove them with `isin`. If the 4th column is called `census-included` you could do

```py
df = df[~df["census-included"].isin(["NO", "Nopes", "Error"])]
```

Otherwise if it's called `Unnamed:3`

```py
df =  df[~df["Unnamed:3"].isin(["NO", "Nopes", "Error"])]
```

Comment: Hey @rpanai, I do not have census-included as header, when I tried with column number number is giving me error:    df =  df[~df[4].isin(["NO", "Nopes", "Error"])]

Comment: Do you mind to share the output of `print(df.columns)`?

Comment: index(['Unamed: 0 ', 'Unnamed: 1', Unnamed: 2, Unnamed:3']0

Comment: I need to remove the whole row where they have these values